# aws private zone for cross vpc connections and ssl cert

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

I am attempting to use an internal aws route53 dns record to provide certificates for my internal routing inside and between VPC. I have created an internal zone in route53 (site.internal) which I was hoping i could then use api.site.internal for applications routing between the zones and internally as well as using a free wildcard certificate for all the subdomains i.e api. .. So, the idea was :

- create internal route53 zone
- - create cname to point at my ALB
- - generate wildcard certificate for (*.site.internal)

Then using this internal dns for curls etc from other vpc's and within the same vpc??

So my question is.. will this work and does it make sense, and allow secure ssl traffic internally using aws certificates?

Thanks in advance and for the help

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In general this is how private Route53 hosted zones work. Note that I'm not sure if AWS's "domain" option for SSL authentication will work with a private zone for issuing ACM certificates - you may want to use email authentication instead.

That having been said, remember that you'll still need to set up VPC peering between your VPCs. You can route the traffic to an IP or load balancer, but if that box can't be reached from your VPC it won't matter.